# How to capture errors using selenium webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, extract-error-message

My tools:-

```
ruby
selenium-webdriver
watir-webdriver
```

Steps:-

1. Opening the form
2. Filling the required details except one field
3. Submit the form

It throws the error as i did't one required field in the form.

How to capture the errors using selenium-webdriver ?

Note: Attached screenshot for reference.
[image]

Comment: Put your code and text of error

Answer (score 0):

The form errors should have some sort of reference that you can use to get the text of the error. You could then use this to check if you are getting the correct errors or not.